# Apache not running

Tags: apache, wordpress, xampp

I need to use Wordpress with XAMPP for a task in a study project.

I installed XAMPP, and now I'm supposed to start MySql and Apache from the Xamp Control Panel.
If I start the panel, it displays:

```
XAMPP Control Panel Version 2.5.8 (2009-07-28)
XAMPP for Windows Version 1.7.3
Windows 5.1 Build 2600 Platform 2 Service Pack 3
CurrentDirectory: C:\xampp
Status Check OK
```

If I click on the Start button for the Apache module, the following two lines are added:

```
Busy...
Apache started
```

But it's not started. It's still Stopped.

I found this thread, describing the same problem with a solution:

<del>http://www.netshinesoftware.com/component/option,com_myblog/Itemid,65/show,Apache-wont-start-on-XAMPP.html/</del>

But Skype is not running. If i check the ports in `cmd` with `netstat -a -no` there is one entry with port 80, but it's from IP adress 0.0.0.0 and the corresponding PID I cannot find in the 'tasklist'

What could be the problem and how can I resolve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look in your error logs to see what Apache says: C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log

And look at Server Fault; that's a better place for Apache and XAMPP questions: [Questions containing 'xampp [apache] wont start' - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=xampp+apache+won%27t+start)

Comment: Hey Songdogtech thanks, that was already helpful. Acoording to the log, the conflict with this 0.0.0.0:80 appears to be the problem. But what could be causing this port already be used? if i check with netstat -a -no i see a PID assigned to that entry, but i cannot find this PID in the tasklist

Comment: Do you also have IIS running? What about a firewall?